# Is the preposition "in" needed here? "Find the jury sheet in pertaining to..."

Tags: grammar, prepositions

1. > Find the jury sheet **in** pertaining to the sports event held at central sports club between 6:30 am and 8:00 am today.
2. > Find the jury sheet pertaining to the sports event held at central sports club between 6:30 am and 8:00 am today.

Which of above two lines are more grammatically correct to write?

Answer (score 1):

Sentence 2 is correct and sentence 1 is incorrect.   You never use an extra preposition in front of "pertaining".

Please see the example sentences from http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/pertaining

Admittedly, pertaining is a participle and many languages use a preposition in front of this type of construction (and some languages don't use the participle, but rather the infinitive in this type of construction), but it would be incorrect in your example sentence to do so.